Drizzle: get all from table (db.select().from()) returns empty array
im starting with drizzle and im fairly new to anything to relating ORMs / serverless functions. I'm using neon with postgres and trying to get all user from the table.
Im using following function:
import { neon } from "@neondatabase/serverless";
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/neon-http";
import { user } from "@/src/schema";
import { sql } from "drizzle-orm";

async function getData() {
  const connectionString = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL;
  if (!connectionString) {
    console.error("Missing DATABASE_URL");
    throw new Error("Missing DATABASE_URL");
  }
  try {
    const client = neon(connectionString);
    const db = drizzle(client);
    const result = await db.select().from(user); // returns []
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error querying database:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

This is returning an empty Array []
while this is returning all users:
import { neon } from "@neondatabase/serverless";
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/neon-http";
import { user } from "@/src/schema";
import { sql } from "drizzle-orm";

async function getData() {
  const connectionString = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL;
  if (!connectionString) {
    console.error("Missing DATABASE_URL");
    throw new Error("Missing DATABASE_URL");
  }
  try {
    const client = neon(connectionString);
    const db = drizzle(client);
    const result = await db.execute(sql`SELECT * FROM ${user}`); // returns [see below]
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error querying database:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

returning:




{
  command: 'SELECT',
  fields: [
    {
      columnID: 1,
      dataTypeID: 23,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      format: 'text',
      name: 'id',
      tableID: 24587
    },
    {
      columnID: 2,
      dataTypeID: 25,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      format: 'text',
      name: 'name',
      tableID: 24587
    },
    {
      columnID: 3,
      dataTypeID: 25,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      format: 'text',
      name: 'email',
      tableID: 24587
    },
    {
      columnID: 4,
      dataTypeID: 25,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      format: 'text',
      name: 'password',
      tableID: 24587
    },
    {
      columnID: 5,
      dataTypeID: 25,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      dataTypeSize: -1,
      format: 'text',
      name: 'role',
      tableID: 24587
    },
    {
      columnID: 6,
      dataTypeID: 1114,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      dataTypeSize: 8,
      format: 'text',
      name: 'created_at',
      tableID: 24587
    },
    {
      columnID: 7,
      dataTypeID: 1114,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      dataTypeSize: 8,
      format: 'text',
      name: 'updated_at',
      tableID: 24587
    }
  ],
  rowAsArray: false,
  rowCount: 2,
  rows: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Jan',
      email: 'jan@mail.de',
      password: 'superPassword',
      role: 'admin',
      created_at: null,
      updated_at: null
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Franz',
      email: 'Beckenbauer',
      password: 'BeckiSchmecki',
      role: 'user',
      created_at: null,
      updated_at: null
    }
  ],
  viaNeonFetch: true
}

what am i doing wrong and why is db.select().from(user) not returning all?
